# Prove this conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I come across an equality to complete a proof in my paper. I think it is true and I confirm by numerically experimenting with different parameter values, and analytically proving this with n=1,2. But I have no clue how to prove the general case.

**Conjecture**

For positive integer $N$ and $n\leq N$, define
\begin{equation*}
c\left( n,N\right) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\rho ^{N+1-n}\left( 1-\rho
\right) ^{n-m}\binom{N-m}{N-n}
\end{equation*}

we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{n+1}{N+1}c\left( n+1,N+1\right) +\frac{N+1-n}{N+1}c\left(
n,N+1\right) = c(n,N)
\end{equation}

I would appreciate if anyone can give a hint...

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $\rho$, such as $\rho\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @Clayton it is a polynomial in $\rho$. If it is true for so many values it is true for all.

Comment: The usual tricks include reindexing the summations so you can combine like terms, and invoking $$ \binom{n}{m} + \binom{n}{m+1} = \binom{n+1}{m+1}$$ I haven't checked that this will actually work here. Another usual trick is asking Mathematica to sum the series for you; I wouldn't be surprised if there was a clsoed form.

Comment: I guess @Hurkyl idea should work. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I followed ABC's steps, used Hurkyl's idea and proved this conjecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice they are just polynomials in $\rho$. So all we need to do is to get them written as sums of powers of the same thing and compare coefficients.

Let us put $b(n,N):=c(n,N)/\rho^{N+1-n}$ then your recurrence is the same as

$$\frac{n+1}{N+1}b(n+1,N+1)+\frac{N+1-n}{N+1}\rho b(n,N+1)=b(n,N)$$

We can re-write $\rho=-(1-\rho)+1$ and get

$$\frac{n+1}{N+1}b(n+1,N+1)+\frac{N+1-n}{N+1}(-(1-\rho)+1) b(n,N+1)=b(n,N)$$

Notice that $b(n,N)$ are just polynomials in $(1-\rho)$. Organize the powers of $1-\rho$ in the left hand side and compare them with those of the right hand side.

There is a general algorithm to construct linear recurrences with rational coefficients for sums of hypergeometric terms due to the nun Sister Celine Fasenmyer. More about this in the book A=B ([free to download](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)).